# Html tag inside paste0() function as replacement in str_replace_all using r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Sample sentence

```
sentence <-'When Sebastian Thrun started at Google in 2007, few people outside of the company took him seriously.'
```

This is the extracted entity from spacyr package:

```
spacy_extract_entity(sentence)
```

[image]

and lookup list I want to assign my own color for the ent_type

```
ent_type <- c('PERSON', 'ORG',  'DATE')
color    <- c('#a3de2a', '#45c4f9', '#2ebaad')
```

How can I return the ent_type and color value and replace in the sentence with html tag using paste0() function as replacement in str_replace_all.

**Example:**

```
paste0('<span style=\"background-color:', color, '\ ">',text,' #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;">',ent_type,'</span></span>')
```

Comment: Show what the sample output is as code instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data frame with the entity names and color, build a dynamic regex out of the parsed sentence `text` column while escaping each value and sorting the alternative chain from longest to shortest, then plug it all in into a `str_replace_all`:

```
library(spacyr)
library(stringr)

## Escaping function
regex.escape <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^${|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}
## Sorting by length in the descending order function
sort.by.length.desc <- function (v) v[order( -nchar(v)) ]

## Input data
sentence <- "IBM is an MNC with headquarters in New York. Oracle is a cloud company in California.James When Sebastian Thrun started at Google in 2007, works in IBM. Oracle hired John for cloud expertise. They give 100% to their profession."
ent_type <- c('PERSON', 'ORG',  'DATE')
color    <- c('#a3de2a', '#45c4f9', '#2ebaad')
ec <- data.frame(ent_type, color)             ## Dataframe with color built
e <- spacy_extract_entity(sentence)

## Build the regex pattern
pat <- paste(regex.escape(sort.by.length.desc(e$text)), collapse="|")
#pat <- paste0("\\b(?:", paste(regex.escape(e$text), collapse="|"), ")\\b") # If whole word search needed use this pattern


str_replace_all(sentence, pat, function(x) 
  paste0('<span style="background-color:', ec$color[ec$ent_type==e$ent_type[e$text == x][1]][1], ' ">',x,' #<span style="font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;">',e$ent_type[e$text == x][1],'</span></span>')
)
## => [1] "<span style=\"background-color:#45c4f9 \">IBM #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;\">ORG</span></span> is an <span style=\"background-color:#45c4f9 \">MNC #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;\">ORG</span></span> with headquarters in <span style=\"background-color:NA \">New York #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;\">GPE</span></span>. Oracle is a cloud company in <span style=\"background-color:NA \">California #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;\">GPE</span></span>.<span style=\"background-color:#a3de2a \">James When #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;\">PERSON</span></span> <span style=\"background-color:#a3de2a \">Sebastian Thrun #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;\">PERSON</span></span> started at <span style=\"background-color:#45c4f9 \">Google #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;\">ORG</span></span> in <span style=\"background-color:#2ebaad \">2007 #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;\">DATE</span></span>, works in <span style=\"background-color:#45c4f9 \">IBM #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;\">ORG</span></span>. Oracle hired <span style=\"background-color:#a3de2a \">John #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;\">PERSON</span></span> for cloud expertise. They give <span style=\"background-color:NA \">100% #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;\">PERCENT</span></span> to their profession."
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to ask why there's an error if I have a sentence of more than 25 words. Here's the errors message: Error in string[[i]] <- `*vtmp*` : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace.

Comment: @bea Add the data to the question so that I could repro.

Comment: This is my sample sentence: "IBM is an MNC with headquarters in New York. Oracle is a cloud company in California.James When Sebastian Thrun started at Google in 2007, works in IBM. Oracle hired John for cloud expertise. They give 100% to their profession."

Comment: @bea Sorry, I did not foresee any dupes in the `text` clolumn. You may dedupe it first, or just use my updated solution.